Is this font actually readable at all, or is it meant as a joke?
I've stumbled on the font named 白舟角崩朱文教漢 at the bottom of this page on j-font.com, you can see it on the bottom of the screenshot:

I can't read it at all, even when I compare with the characters in the font above, which are supposed to be the same. If I squint I can see a small resemblance, but I'm definitely not capable of reading it.
Is this a font that a Japanese person would be able to read? Or is it just meant as a joke?


Is this a font that a Japanese person would be able to read?

Not at all. FWIW, the 草書 and 篆書 variants in your link are already difficult enough for average native Japanese speakers.

Or is it just meant as a joke?

This is not a joke but rather a type of traditional 江戸文字. This typeface is not meant for easy reading. Think of this as an established art form, much like English street graffiti, which is often extremely difficult for average people to decipher.
This typeface seems to have been mainly used for making seals or printing logos on clothing.

Thank you very much, the font matches perfectly with the 角字 (Kakuji) style! The link also explains the potential uses of the other typefaces from the website ^^

This is an instance of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-fold_seal_script, an ornamental Chinese script. While the characters do “straighten” out to something like a regular script, these were only used in an ornamental capacity.

Thank you! From your answer and @naruto's answer, it does seem like this is mostly used for seals, or as they suggest maybe also for printing logos on clothing.
